# Is untanned klaf kosher?

Tags: safrus

A recent article ([here](http://www.hakirah.org/vol21Hoffman.pdf)) was written by Rabbi Hoffman. He writes that the Mishnah lays out a detailed process for tanning klaf, which was held as the only kasher form of parchment by nearly all sages for StaM until Rabbeinu Tam, who ruled that the intention of the halakha was to create a surface suited for writing.

The article calls into question the acceptability of untanned (white) hides that are commonly used and encourages us to adapt the Gevil/Gewil.

Must we stop using untanned klaf, or is untanned klaf kosher/acceptable?

Comment: As you said it is a Machloket Rishonim. What else do you want from us? Go ask your rabbi which opinions you should be stringent for.